# Wix Installer - Changing a CustomAction on a Patch

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation

I am using Wix Toolset to create .msi and .msp files. I currently have a custom action defined in my applicaton's .wxs file that is run whenever the application is upgraded via a patch or an reinstall of a newer version of the app. This CustomAction runs at the appropriate time and is working correctly.

I need to modify the ExecCommand property of the CustomAction a little bit. I would like it so that the .msp file I create will result in the modified CustomAction to run on update. I modified the .wxs file for the newer version of the application, created a patch between the two versions and verified that this will not run the updated custom action.

Is there any way to update a CustomAction with a patch?  Is there something else I need to put into the PatchFamily portion into the patch's .wxs file? It currently is very simple and only contains two ComponentRef tags of two new files that are added for the patch.

Comment: What kind of patch is this? Minor, major?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul it is a minor patch.

Comment: You'll need to say if the custom action exe is being run from the Binary table, or if it's an installed exe and so on.